# How to set action in multiple buttons in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode

this is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *segmentTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               NSLocalizedString(@"button1", @""),
                               NSLocalizedString(@"button2", @""),
                               NSLocalizedString(@"button3", @""), nil];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] nitWithItems:segmentTextContent];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 30);

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
[segmentedControl release];
}
```

three buttons are displayed but i don't know how to set action in button help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add target at the time of segmentedControl creation like below

```
 [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

> in that selector

```
-(IBAction) segmentAction:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
        NSLog(@"Segment clicked: %d", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
              self.segmentLabel.text =@"Segment 1 selected.";
              break;
            case 1:
              self.segmentLabel.text =@"Segment 2 selected.";
              break;

            default:
               break;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 3 buttons and add them to an UIToolbar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// create a toolbar to have the buttons at the right side of the navigationBar
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44.01)];
    toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [toolbar setTranslucent:YES];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    // Create button1
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(button1Pressed)];
    [buttons addObject:button1];
    [button1 release];

    // Create button2
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(button2Pressed)];
    [buttons addObject:button2];
    [button2 release];

    // Create button3
    UIBarButtonItem *button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(button3Pressed)];
    [buttons addObject:button3];
    [button3 release];

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
    [toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    //self.toolbarItems = buttons;
    [buttons release];

    // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease]];
    [toolbar release];
} 

...

 - (void)button1Pressed
{
   //do stuff
}

 - (void)button2Pressed
{
   //do stuff
}

 - (void)button3Pressed
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: It is not really meant to have multiple button there but if you want to switch the buttons just switch the input of the array of buttons. In the width of the CGRectMake in the UIToolbar initialisation you can get them more to the left. (I see an error in my code, I fixed it)

Comment: BTW, `propertiesButton` -> `button1`, `commentaryButton` -> `button2` and `versionsButton` -> `button3`. It did work better for me than other methods (due to space restrictions), but I'll have to do more to it to make it blend with everything else

Comment: @Warpspace Thank you. I didn't changed all what I copy-pasted from my own code.

Comment: Oh, and I used `[toolBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] autorelease] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` to completely hide the toolbar's background. Only available in iOS 5+, though.